# Saturation Mask in LAB mode

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How can I create a saturation mask in Photoshop within the LAB colour mode?

In default RGB you can use the filter `HSB/HSL` to create an image with a saturation channel, but it is not available in LAB.

Comment: Not all filters are available in all image modes.  Perhaps you could convert the LAB image to a Smart Object. Set the image mode of the main document to RGB. The Smart Object will still contain a LAB iamge. Then apply the HSB/HSL filter to the Smart Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Photoshop term saturation actually means chroma if the color mode is Lab. Unfortunately no polar version of Lab is not included, so you must extract the chroma from coordinates a and b of the Lab colors. Those a and b  are shown in the color selector as integers from -128 to +127, but in the Channels panel they are shown as grayscale images having brightness values 0...255. Brightness zero means a or b value -128, brightness 128 means a or b value zero and brightness 255 means a or b value +127.

In Lab system the numeric chroma - or the saturation, as Photoshop misleadingly calls it - could be calculated with the well known Pythagorean formula - that's the squareroot of the sum of the squares - from the a and b color coordinates assuming they were scaled from -128 to +127. But as said, they have offset +128 to keep the numbers positive.

The +128 offset is no problem, but the big problem is that Photoshop's user interface offers no direct method to calculate anything from a and b. Your case needs a programmer or a 3rd party plugin (no idea which one) or a tricky workaround. We continue along the workaround-route.

Learn this before you continue: Do not get confused if yo happen to see for ex. in the curves tool grayscale image brightnesses presented as black ink percentages. Photoshop has there an option to select if the brightness is shown as the amount of light scaled from 0 to 255 or as "black ink percentage" from 100% to 0%. The actual pixels are handled fortunately consistently - black is black, grey is grey and white is white.

The workaround: If your image has multiple layers make a copy of the image and merge the layers. One who knows what he does could as well make a layer group, but I skip it and talk of a single layer image.

1. Insert a new empty layer below your image layer.
2. Let the image layer have blending mode saturation
3. Fill the new layer with color L=50, a=0, b=127. That's a dark and dirty looking yellow. Your image looks like it has only grey and that yellow. The chroma of your image layer is all in the b-channel.
4. Merge the layers to make the chroma of the whole image accessible and copyable in the Channels panel.
5. In the Channels panel close all other channels, except b. Select all and press Ctrl+C to catch the chroma values to the clipboard.
6. Start a new image. Photoshop should offer from the clipboard a grayscale image which has the same pixel dimensions as the original Lab color image. Accept it and paste the clipboard content. That's your chroma, presented as brightnesses.

The chroma is unfortunately compressed to scale 128...255. You must use levels or curves to stretch the scale to start from 0. The top end does not reach 255 if the Lab image had only colors which fit into the RGB range.

The resolution - only 128 levels (maybe only 100, if the colors fit into RGB range)  and  - may be too little for some applications. But you can help it by using image bit depth 16 bit per channel. That must be done from the start in the Lab mode. Adjusting only the grayscale image does not insert the effective level resolution.